# Inconsistent Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php

I have a php form where a user showed me that they received a fatal error:

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files\Apache2.2\htdocs\eeallparts\registration.php on line 282.
```

What is odd is that they resubmitted the form again and the form worked as it is supposed to inserted the data into the database so this isn't a consistent error.  I get quite a few submissions on the form (a fair degree of them spam) so I know that the form usually works, but this random error bothers me obviously.

I went to the line 282 and the only thing I see is this:

```
if(!$insertContact_query = mssql_query($sql)) {
```

I read a couple of the other threads related to this that suggested to look at the [set time limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).  If the query simply takes too long wouldn't the query virtually always time out instead of periodically time out?  I had the user resubmit the same information in the form and it worked the second time?

Comment: How much work is your page doing? Is it adding hundreds of rows of data, or just a couple?

Comment: It's possible there's an issue with the underlying SQL server itself (performance issues, fragmentation, etc...), or with any PHP caching you have (dis/en)abled.

Comment: "If the query simply takes too long wouldn't the query virtually" No it could be a locking issue that happens depending on collisions. It could take longer during traffic peaks, ...

Comment: If you post your SQL query, we can give it a quick look too, but it's possible that you're missing an index or you have some other edgecase in your SQL, but I would also agree it looks like SQL to me

Comment: Did you tried to restart mysql or apache service?

Comment: Perhaps you could accept a few answers?

Answer (score 1):

The time limit doesn't include time spent on any external data sources like time it takes to query the database.

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

If the query returns large dataset it may timeout simply during processing the set. If possible use php profile to indicate bottlenecks.

Comment: "This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.", if you look closely at the problem, you'll see the poster is running Windows. The SQL query/engine can certainly cause this.

Comment: You're right. I've always used Linux in my php dev and didn't notice that.